# HTTPD using same port multiple times

Tags: apache-httpd, tomcat

I am running 3 tomcat in cluster ( different httpd & AJP13 ports ) with a apache in the front.

It looks like only one tomcat stays up and other two error out in jkstatus manager

[image: screenshot]

The error logs suggest the port is bound already

```
30-Oct-2017 21:53:09.794 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8006]: 
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:704)
```

Running a netstat suggest the same

```
[root@dev logs]# netstat -anop | grep 8009
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      28887/java           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8009                ::1:58801               ESTABLISHED 28887/java           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:58791               ::1:8009                ESTABLISHED 29719/httpd          off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:58801               ::1:8009                ESTABLISHED 29709/httpd          off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8009                ::1:58807               ESTABLISHED 28887/java           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:58807               ::1:8009                ESTABLISHED 29705/httpd          off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8009                ::1:58803               ESTABLISHED 28887/java           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:58803               ::1:8009                ESTABLISHED 29706/httpd          off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8009                ::1:58805               ESTABLISHED 28887/java           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:58805               ::1:8009                ESTABLISHED 29708/httpd          off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8009                ::1:58791               ESTABLISHED 28887/java           off (0.00/
```

I have checked the server.xml files for the different instances of tomcat and dont see a port used again in http/ajp13 ports.

Any idea what might be causing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the impression you know this already: since you’re running your Tomcat instances listening on the same IP address, you need to make sure that every single port that Tomcat uses is set up differently in each instance. This includes the shutdown port: you could use 8006, 8007 and 8008 for example (assuming nothing else uses those ports).

Alternative approaches include using containers to host the instances, or network namespaces. That way you can use the same ports in each instance.

Comment: Hi Stephen,

Thank you for the feedback. I am using port 8006-8 for the shutdown port. I checked again and its not being used in the tomcat ( at least) let me figure out if something else is using the port.

Appreciate your support!